# How to Insert cell reference in VBA code for connecting weburl

Tags: excel, vba

**Note:I dont have any coding experience**

How to insert cell reference in VBA Code for connecting to web url??

Suppose in "A1" cell I'll get the Url for connection. how to connect with the cell "A1" instead of fixed code in VBA Editor....

Please help me... [I've highlighted with blue colour in the image. in that url place I want cell reference for connection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MihIU.jpg)

Once again I'm telling I dont have any coding experience.
Can you please tell me how to modify that.
If you want to test that I'll provide entire code..

```
    Option Explicit
Sub BankNiftyOptionChain()
        
        Dim Json As Object
        Dim webURL As String, mainString, subString
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim dtArr() As String
        
        webURL = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"
        subString = "Resource not found"
        
FetchAgain:


    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", webURL, False
        
        'The following two statements are important to remove cached results.
        
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        
        .send
        
        mainString = .responseText

If InStr(mainString, subString) <> 0 Then

' Data has not been fetched properly. Will wait two seconds and try again.

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
GoTo FetchAgain

Else

' Data has been fetched properly. Proceed to the next step.

Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(mainString)

End If
        
    End With
        
        j = 4
        
        ' Formatting Header Values
        
        Sheet1.Activate
        
        Cells.Clear
        Range("B1").Value = Json("records")("underlyingValue")
        dtArr = Split(Json("records")("timestamp"), " ")
        Range("C1").Value = FormatDateTime(dtArr(0), 2)
        Range("D1").Value = FormatDateTime(dtArr(1), 4)
        
        Range("A2:f2").MergeCells = True
        Range("A2").Value = "CALLS"
        Range("g2").Value = Json("records")("expiryDates")(1)
        Range("h2:m2").MergeCells = True
        Range("H2").Value = "PUTS"
        Range("A1").Value = "BANKNIFTY"
        
        Dim headerValues As Variant
        '  headerValues = VBA.Array("OI", "Change in OI", "IV", "Volume", "Change in Price", "LTP", "Strike Price", "LTP", "Change in Price", "Volume", "IV", "Change in OI", "OI")
        headerValues = VBA.Array("OI", "Change in OI", "IV", "Volume", "Change in Price", "LTP", "Strike Price", "LTP", "Change in Price", "Volume", "IV", "Change in OI", "OI")
        Range("A3:m3").Value = headerValues
        
        Range("A1:m3").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        
        For i = 1 To Json("records")("data").Count
        
        If Json("records")("data")(i)("expiryDate") = Json("records")("expiryDates")(1) Then
        
        If Abs(Json("records")("data")(i)("strikePrice") - Json("records")("underlyingValue")) Then
        
        k = 1
        
        ' START OF OI DATA FOR THE CHOSEN EXPIRY DATE
        
        ' the following attributes can also be loaded
        ' strikePrice, expiryDate, underlying, identifier, openInterest, changeinOpenInterest,
        ' pchangeinOpenInterest, totalTradedVolume, impliedVolatility, lastPrice, change, pChange,
        ' totalBuyQuantity, totalSellQuantity, bidQty, bidprice, askQty, askPrice, underlyingValue
        
        If IsObject(Json("records")("data")(i)("CE")) Then
        Cells(j, k).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("CE")("openInterest")
        Cells(j, k + 1).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("CE")("changeinOpenInterest")
        Cells(j, k + 2).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("CE")("impliedVolatility")
        Cells(j, k + 3).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("CE")("totalTradedVolume")
        Cells(j, k + 4).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("CE")("change")
        Cells(j, k + 5).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("CE")("lastPrice")
        Else
        Cells(j, k).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 1).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 2).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 3).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 4).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 5).Value = ""
        End If
        
        If IsObject(Json("records")("data")(i)("PE")) Then
        Cells(j, k + 6).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("PE")("strikePrice")
        Cells(j, k + 7).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("PE")("lastPrice")
        Cells(j, k + 8).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("PE")("change")
        Cells(j, k + 9).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("PE")("totalTradedVolume")
        Cells(j, k + 10).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("PE")("impliedVolatility")
        Cells(j, k + 11).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("PE")("changeinOpenInterest")
        Cells(j, k + 12).Value = Json("records")("data")(i)("PE")("openInterest")
        
        Else
        Cells(j, k + 6).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 7).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 8).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 9).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 10).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 11).Value = ""
        Cells(j, k + 12).Value = ""
        End If
        
        ' END OF OI DATA FOR THE CHOSEN EXPIRY DATE
        
        j = j + 1
        
        End If
        
        End If
        
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You could put "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY" in cell A1 and then write `webURL = Cells(1,"A").Value`. // If BANKNIFTY is one of several symbols then you need to loop i.e. `"webURL = https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=" & Cells(i, "A").Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL is in `A1` of the active sheet you could use this.

```vb
 webURL = Range("A1").Value
```

If you want to refer to `A1` on a specific sheet, e.g. `Sheet1`, you could use this.

```vb
 webURL = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```